# IP addressing/subnetting

Tags: ip

I am an IT Administrator for a newly founded company and have been tasked with designing an IP addressing scheme and a plan for allocation and management of IP addresses.
The company will currently have a single, physical location with approximately 145 hosts (computers, printers, etc.)

1. What subnet ranges should be used?
2. Should IP addresses be dynamically or statically assigned?
3. Should one or more network/subnets be used?
4. If DHCP is used, should a router, firewall or Windows Server be utilized and why?

I need to consider future growth and design also

Comment: Sounds like a homework question... do it yourself.

Comment: If you are really interested in subnetting, you need to do some serious study. Some ready made solution from others will never allow you to cope with changes or future growths. Since you are an IT administrator, I presume that you have enough backgrounds to quickly grasp the topics. Look for subnetting over Internet, and study the materials. But remember, understanding subnetting needs real devotion and willingness to learn. For some people, it can be mind baffling.

Answer (score 0):

If there are 145 hosts. I would use /24 or 255.255.255.0 subnet.
Printers should be statically assigned.( This is just me)
DHCP should definitely be used, you don't want to assign the ip adresses of 145 computers statically. That would take forever.

Make sure you only have 1 DHCP server. You can have two, but it just depends on your set up.

Answer (score 0):

I normally assign 10.0.0.0/22 (255.255.252.0) giving a range of 10.0.0.0 - 10.0.3.255.
This gives you a mass of space. From this then I normally do the following:

- 10.0.0.1-255 dedicated for critical network devices e.g. switches / access points / firewalls / routers servers etc
- 10.0.1.1-255 for printers / network scanners and user specific devices
- which leaves 10.0.2.1 - 10.0.3.255 used by DHCP for clients e.g. desktops / laptops / mobile devices (BYOD)

Have done this several times now and works well especially as companies grow you can then do the same practice with 10.1.0.0/22 for the second site.